# Proving that a square is made by connecting point-opposite midpoint in larger square

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Below is a diagram of a square, where $E, H, F,$ and $G$ are the midpoints of the square. I want to prove that the smaller square formed by the intersections of $EC, FD, BH,$ and $AG$ is a square.

[image]

So far, I see a lot of right angles but I can't seem to manipulate them. I tried to use coordinate geometry, like settings a point for $D$ and another point for $F.$ I also know the altitude to hypotenuse of a right triangle splits it into three similar triangles, but that isn't really useful, since we want to show that when the altitude is dropped, it will intersect the square at another midpoint. Could I have some help? Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several ways to proceed. Here is one possible approach: 1) Can you show that the lines are at right angles to each other? 2) Can you show that the line segments are the same length?

Comment: For 1), the only approach I can think of is if we made a formula for the lines of them, and if the slopes are the negative of the reciprocals of each other, they would be at right angles to each other, but I don't think that's the nicest, most rigorous approach. For 2),  I think they're the same length since you could take two triangles, and LL congruence, the triangles are congruent, so the hypotenuse, or the line segments would be of same length.

Comment: 1) Yes, that works. You can calculate the slopes quite easily. 2) Yup, that works too.

Comment: @CalvinLin Wait, something I'm not completely sure on is that if we know that the line segments are equal, how do we necessarily know that when they intersect, the segments that make the smaller square will also be equal?

Comment: Can you write up what you have? That makes it easier for me to see what you're thinking of. IE What you stated could work, if applied on the right stuff (and it seems like you're not applying them correctly).

Comment: So far, I know that the slopes are negative reciprocals of each other, so the quadrilateral made by the intersections of the line segments are at right angles. I also know the line segments are of equal length, ($AG=EG=BH=FD$). However, I'm not sure how these four segments being equal implies the quadrilateral formed by the intersections of thes segments have equal side lengths

Comment: Can you label the internal points? (say IJKL). Then show that $IJ=JK$. That's what I meant by 2) above. Translate the line segments to form a nice right triangles with a known hypotenuse and angle, hence they are congruent.

Comment: Oh ok, let me try that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more abstract approach. Consider the rotation $R$ that takes $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$, and so on. The square $ABCD$ is obviously invariant under this rotation.

In fact, the entire construction of the inner quadrilateral is also invariant under $R$: for example, $R$ takes $E$ to $F$, $F$ to $G$, and so on.

That means the inner quadrilateral itself is also invariant under $R$. So its four sides and four angles are all equal, which means it's a square.